The stb_image.h library gives a segmentation fault when using clang
I am writing a project an opengl project where i need to read a png file from memory and store the bytes in a buffer. For this I am using the stb_image library. The only two lines of code which comes from this library in my program are these:
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
m_localBuffer = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &m_width, &m_height, &m_BBP, 4);

I build the project with both MinGW and MSVC and I had no problems. The project compiled fine and executed without any errors. With clang however, the project crashed. I tracked a seg fault to the stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit function, on line 1283. The problem is connected to the stbi__vertically_flip_on_load variable. I tried disabling stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load, but still got a seg fault.
From this reddit post I found that removing thread_local from stbi__vertically_flip_on_load would fix the problem. After some more investigation I ended up adding these lines of code to the top of the program.
#ifdef __clang__
   #define STBI_NO_THREAD_LOCALS 1
#endif

While this is a decent workaround for anyone having the same problem, I still don't understand why it is necessary. The project description gives me the idea that is should just work without adding any extra code. I have not seen anyone else having the same problem. I don't like the idea of not having thread_local variables if I were to expand upon the project later.
My question is: why does stb_image give me a seg fault when compiling with clang, and is there a way to fix this without losing thread_local functionality?
I am using windows with an AMD ryzen processor.
Update: Turns out I was using a version of Clang with a known bug with the thread_local keyword. Upgrading to a newer version of Clang fixed the problem. So not an issue with stb_image.

My suspicion is that there is a bug in STB, and STBI_NO_THREAD_LOCALS is a kluge to workaround the bug.  (But I'd worry there is a still a bug even with that define.)  Sean Barrett says bug 856 discovered 2019 in stb_image.h v2.23 has been fixed in stb_image.h v2.24 (2020).  It appears you using v2.24 or later (current version is 2.30), since that is when STBI_NO_THREAD_LOCALS was added.

I am assuming you're referring to this https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues/856. There seems to still be a bug and it was not obvious to me that STBI_NO_THREAD_LOCALS was a workaround. One of the reason for the post was the suspicion that this bug would pop up again later when my program grew in complexity. Also I am using the latest v2.30 of stb_image

I agree.  I have the same suspicion.  If you find a bug(s), and fix it/them, submit a pull request to Sean Barrett.

Maybe consider giving CImg a try - it's cross-platform and header-only http://cimg.eu/

I have also look at lodepng as an option. It is also a single header library
